# AngularJS - Unauthorized and interceptors

Tags: angularjs

Im working with angularjs and Im trying to handle errors with interceptors.

I have run into the issue of how handling the different error **session expires** with **login failed** when server replies both with 401.

It seems that **interceptors** defined in the **config will execute before any other interceptors** (order definition matters):

```
var configInterceptor = function($httpProvider)
  {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('unauthorizedInterceptor');
  };

angular.module('app', [])
       .config(configInterceptor)
       .controller....
```

The **interceptors defined in the $resource** will be considered **only after they have gone through the configInterceptor**.

```
var res = $resource(serviceUrl + '/users/login',{},{
            post:{
                method:'POST',
                params: {},
                withCredentials: true,
                interceptor: {
                  responseError: function(){
                    console.log('login interceptor');
                  }
                }
            }
        });
```

I would like to have a **single point for controlling when the session has expired** (pushing the user to the login page and sending an appropriate message) **without the need to add the unauthorizedInterceptor to all $resources**, one by one.

If the **error is due to users trying to log in and failed, then the interceptor should treat it differently (message will be different).**

Any way to resolve this properly? I tried also defining interceptors to only be applied to a specific module but they are triggered.

Comment: All interceptor will be triggered. You can just check url in your interceptor if it matches login path then do your handling otherwise skip it, Similarly create an interceptor for authentication failure handling and perform work conditionally

Comment: Because we are using angular, there is a session service that tells me when user is connected. Checking if user session is set up helped me handle conditionally the interception of it. Same solution as you said but instead of checking url Im checking for session object. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: This is a stateful solution, you should check what happens when the user opens a new tab. This should trigger "Session expired" instead of login failed (IMO). Anyways, if your server only returns 401 with no message it would be impossible to know the right way to handle this. Is there a message? You could inspect the parameter of your `responseError` handler in the `unauthorizedInterceptor`, it should have something meaningful inside.

Comment: The main issue is that I dont have access to the server. We should have gone to the token authentication to avoid states but that's another history. Due to we are in angularjs, whenever you open a new tab the code start executing, ajax called is done to check if user is authenticated already (but it will return that it is not) and gone back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

```
angular.module('app', []).factory('unauthorizedInterceptor', unauthorizedInterceptor);

function unauthorizedInterceptor($q, ngUserAuthService) {

    return {
        'responseError': function (response) {

            if (response.status === 401) {
                // find out if the session has expired or the user login has failed
                if (sessionExpired()) {
                    doRedirectToSomewhere();
                } else if (loginHasFailed()) {
                    response.loginFailed = true; // use this later
                }
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}
```

And then only add an interceptor to the $resource when you want to check for failed login:

```
var res = $resource(serviceUrl + '/users/login',{},{
    post:{
        method:'POST',
        params: {},
        withCredentials: true,
        interceptor: {
            responseError: function(response) {
                console.log('login interceptor');
                console.log('The login has failed: ' + response.loginFailed);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's how I made it. Thanks